# Vagrant debugging python/django on Pycharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to debug Django project inside Vagrant.

I did searched for the answers and read all available documentations about Vagrant, Remote debugging with Pycharm and more.

What I do have now is perfectly working "Run" command

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/home/vagrant/dev-projects/OP_3.0/bin/python2.7 -u
 /home/vagrant/dev-projects/3.0/online_platform/manage.py runserver 8000

0 errors found
April 06, 2014 - 02:32:40
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'local_settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I can access to it from HOST, and everything works just as suposed to.
But when I'm trying run a "Debug" command I have this:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/home/vagrant/dev-projects/OP_3.0/bin/python2.7 -u
 /home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client '0.0.0.0' --port 34117 --file /home/vagrant/dev-projects/3.0/online_platform/manage.py runserver 8000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 310, in OnRun
    self.handleExcept()
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1414, in handleExcept
    ReaderThread.handleExcept(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 329, in handleExcept
    GlobalDebuggerHolder.globalDbg.FinishDebuggingSession()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FinishDebuggingSession'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1497, in <module>
    dispatcher.connect(host, port)
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1400, in connect
    self.reader.run()
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 252, in run
    self.OnRun()
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 325, in OnRun
    self.handleExcept()
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1414, in handleExcept
    ReaderThread.handleExcept(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 329, in handleExcept
    GlobalDebuggerHolder.globalDbg.FinishDebuggingSession()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FinishDebuggingSession'

Process finished with exit code 1`
```

Any real help, please...

Comment: What is your project interpreter set to? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Comment: We have this problem in our development environment.

Comment: Could you not use virtualenvs? I know there are lots of times when they are not suited but they can assist wiht this type of problem

Comment: Has you solved it? if so please share your solution, I have the same problem in my script, even when I not used django neither vagrant, just ssh remote python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

If you

1. [Let your PyCharm project configuration know](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/vagrant.html) about the project's vagrant box
2. Set up a remote interpreter of type `Vagrant` referencing the right python executable within the vagrant box
3. Use that remote interpreter as your project's python interpreter

then you shouldn't have to fuss around with `ssh` and with debugger command lines yourself anymore. Just tell PyCharm what you want to debug as if it were a local process. (Might work even better if you also let PyCharm know that it's dealing with a Django project.)